# How to add custom icon in liferay clay?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, clay

I want to add WhatsApp icon in Liferay and use clay ui then how to add whatsapp icon in clay with liferay.

```
<clay:link
   buttonStyle="outline-secondary"
   elementClasses="btn-monospaced btn-outline-borderless btn-sm lfr-portal-tooltip"
   href="#link"
   icon="phone"
   title="title"
/>
```

Comment: Add font-awesome library, it's simpler

Comment: I can't use other cause, create the same behavior as the default Liferay theme

Comment: Another good example why crossposts are evil. The problem was solved 16 days ago in a crosspost. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824/364505

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was solved, see this issue in GitHub.

https://github.com/liferay/clay/issues/3690